# What is the meaning of "be good to beat the White Cloud" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "It would be good to beat the White Cloud" in the following sentence,

> The Rainbird sailed away from New York Harbor, bound for California.
>   Captain Murdock stood by the wheel giving orders to the crew. Mrs.
>   Murdock stood beside him. "Pray for good weather, Mary Elizabeth," the
>   captain said. "***It would be good to beat the White Cloud***." Jamie
>   and Meg said good-bye to their home in New York. "Maybe we will find
>   gold in California," said Meg. (Source: CLIPPER SHIP BY THOMAS
>   P.LEWIS)

Does "It would be good to beat the White Cloud" mean "He predicted the weather. He said that white cloud is likely to occur"?

Comment: Without having read the book, I can only guess that **White Cloud** is the name of another ship that the captain would like to beat in a fair-weather "race" to California.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the context, and the fact that it is capitalised (and therefore a proper noun), it would appear that *White Cloud* is **the name of another ship**. The captain of the *Rainbird* would like his ship to beat the other ship, the *White Cloud*, to their destination - which is to say, get there before they do.